# How to change constraints to a button who has been created programatically?

Tags: ios, swift2, constraints

I would like to move a programatically created button using constraints that have been programatically created to that button. But I'm running into a couple of errors. I was able to do this to a button that was created not programatically with constraints also created not programatically. Heres the code:

```
var displayLink: CADisplayLink?
var startTime: CFAbsoluteTime?
let duration = 2.0
@IBOutlet var TopConstraintforMoving1: NSLayoutConstraint!  
@IBAction func Startbutton(sender: UIButton) {
    startDisplayLink()
}
func startDisplayLink() {
    displayLink?.invalidate()
    startTime = CFAbsoluteTimeGetCurrent()
    displayLink = CADisplayLink(target: self, selector: "handleDisplayLink:")
    displayLink?.addToRunLoop(NSRunLoop.mainRunLoop(), forMode: NSRunLoopCommonModes)
func handleDisplayLink(displayLink: CADisplayLink) {
    let elapsed = CFAbsoluteTimeGetCurrent() - startTime!
    var percentComplete = CGFloat(elapsed / duration)
    if percentComplete >= 1.0 {
        percentComplete = 1.0
        stopDisplayLink()
    }
    TopConstraintforMoving1.constant = 390 - 350 * percentComplete
}
```

This is the code I have for the button that was created programatically:

```
var startTime: CFAbsoluteTime?
let duration = 2.0
let button = UIButton(type: UIButtonType.System) as UIButton
var topConstraintforMoving1: NSLayoutConstraint?  
@IBAction func StartButton(sender: UIButton) {
    startTime = CFAbsoluteTimeGetCurrent()
    let elapsed = CFAbsoluteTimeGetCurrent() - startTime!
    var percentComplete = CGFloat(elapsed / duration)
    if percentComplete >= 1.0 {
        percentComplete = 1.0
    }
    button.setImage(UIImage(named: "BlueBall.png")!, forState: UIControlState.Normal)
    button.addTarget(self, action: "buttonAction:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
    view.addSubview(button)
    button.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false      
    topConstraintforMoving1 = button.topAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(view.topAnchor, constant: 390 - 350 * percentComplete)  
    NSLayoutConstraint.activateConstraints([
        button.leadingAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(view.leadingAnchor, constant: 122),
        button.topAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(view.topAnchor, constant: 393),
        button.widthAnchor.constraintEqualToConstant(75),
        button.heightAnchor.constraintEqualToConstant(75),
        ])      
}
```

The button doesn't move.
Please help.Thank you. Anton

Comment: BTW, using a CADisplayLink and manually changing the constraint's constant on each frame is not recommended. It's better to use a UIView animation like animateWithDuration:animations: where you change the constraint and call layoutIfNeeded inside the animation block.

Comment: Ya but then I can't click the button in the middle of the animation

Comment: "Ya but then I can't click the button in the middle of the animation" Yes, you can. Perhaps it would be better if you asked about _that_!

Comment: @matt I'm just reading your comments about the UIButton animation and I agree with your statement about using UIVIew animation blocks, but I'm currently facing a similar issue with a UIWebView. As the webView animates, it becomes untouchable and there is no way of forwarding the touch events to the webVIews contents How would you recommend changing constraints with CADisplayLink?

Comment: "How would you recommend changing constraints with CADisplayLink" Same answer. I wouldn't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I retried to build this in a different way but using the same methods and it worked. Here's the code:

```
let button = UIButton()
var displayLink: CADisplayLink?
var startTime: CFAbsoluteTime?
let duration = 2.0
var topConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!
@IBAction func start(sender: UIButton) {
    displayLink?.invalidate()
    startTime = CFAbsoluteTimeGetCurrent()
    displayLink = CADisplayLink(target: self, selector: "handleDisplayLink:")
    displayLink?.addToRunLoop(NSRunLoop.mainRunLoop(), forMode: NSRunLoopCommonModes)
}
func handleDisplayLink(displayLink: CADisplayLink) {
    button.hidden = false
    let elapsed = CFAbsoluteTimeGetCurrent() - startTime!
    var percentComplete = CGFloat(elapsed / duration)
    if percentComplete >= 1.0 {
        percentComplete = 1.0
        displayLink.invalidate()
        button.hidden = true
    }
    topConstraint.constant = 393 - 350 * percentComplete
    NSLayoutConstraint.activateConstraints([
        button.leadingAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(view.leadingAnchor, constant: 122),
        topConstraint,
        button.widthAnchor.constraintEqualToConstant(75),
        button.heightAnchor.constraintEqualToConstant(75)
        ])
}
func buttonPressed(sender: UIButton!) {
    button.hidden = true
    displayLink?.invalidate()
}
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    button.hidden = true
    button.setImage(UIImage(named: "BlueBall.png")!, forState: UIControlState.Normal)
    button.addTarget(self, action: "buttonPressed:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
    self.view.addSubview(button)
    button.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    topConstraint = button.topAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(view.topAnchor, constant: 393)  
    NSLayoutConstraint.activateConstraints([
        button.leadingAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(view.leadingAnchor, constant: 122),
        topConstraint,
        button.widthAnchor.constraintEqualToConstant(75),
        button.heightAnchor.constraintEqualToConstant(75)
        ])   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're on the right track. In your code that creates your button in code, you're also creating a constraint in code. However, you're not saving a pointer to that constraint.

(The return type of the function `constraintEqualToAnchor` is NSLayoutConstraint, but you are not saving that return value anywhere.)

Create an instance variable and save your constraint to that variable. You can even tag the constraint as an IBOutlet if you like.

Then manipulate the constant value of your constraint just like you are doing with your buttons that are created in IB (Interface Builder.)

### EDIT:

Your code might look like this:

```
TopConstraintforMoving1 = 
  button.topAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(
    view.topAnchor, 
    constant: 390 - 350 * percentComplete)
```

Note that variable names should start with a lower case letter, so that could should really be:

```
topConstraintforMoving1 = 
  button.topAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(
    view.topAnchor, 
    constant: 390 - 350 * percentComplete)
```

Comment: How do I save the instance to the constraint?

Comment: You mean how do you save the constraint to the instance variable? See the edit to my answer.

Comment: So to create topConstraintforMoving1, I would have to do this: var topConstraintforMoving1 = NSLaysoutConstraint() ?

Comment: No. You'd want var `var topConstraintforMoving1: NSLaysoutConstraint`. You should not create an instance of  NSLaysoutConstraint in your variable declaration because it will never be used.

Comment: Thank you. Now on the top (class (name) : UIViewController{ //code }), it says: class (name) has no initializers

Comment: So make it an optional: `var topConstraintforMoving1: NSLaysoutConstraint?`

Comment: It still doesn't work. I'm going to update he second code in my question so you can see if I did anything wrong.

Comment: I haven't done much with programmatically added constraints. At a glance, shouldn't you create `topConstraintforMoving1` before the call to `activateConstraints` and add it to the list of constraints that you activate?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/98864/discussion-between-anton-o-and-duncan-c).